Regular expression to find longest sequence of 0 in between 1 in a binary string
I am trying to write a regular expression to identify all the consecutive sequences of zeroes between 1 in a binary string. I am then trying to iterate over these matches to identify the longest such subsequence of 0.
Following are examples for problem statement:

For 7 the binary code is 111 and hence the count of longest subsequence of 0 is => 0.
For 5 the binary code is 101 and hence the count of longest subsequence of 0 is => 1.
For 10 the binary code is 1010 and hence the count of longest subsequence of 0 is => 1.

So, I came up with this regular expression:
1[0]+1 and (10*)1 that works for most of my cases. However, it is not working for certain set of values that have continuous occurrences of long sequences of 0s enclosed within 1. One such example is as followed:

For integer **145 ** the binary code is 10010001 and regular expression is only able to identify the first occurrence of 1001 and does not identify the later sequence 10001 which obviously is the longest sub-sequence. And, thus, I get my output as 2 instead of 3.


0+ should be enough, no?

It would help if you share your actual code. Otherwise we can not exclude that you perhaps just applied the regex wrong within your program. Such as not using while (matcher.find()) but perhaps matcher.matches() or similar.

if I understand the problem it is like in for example in 101001 it will only find the first sequence 101, second sequence 1001 is not found since the 1 is already consumed - maybe zero-width positive lookahead and lookbehind helps (like in (?<=1)0+(?=1)) -- its almost like 0+ from first comment, but it guarantees that there are 1s before and after the zeros

You could use a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to match any sequence of zeros enclosed in ones.
(?<=1)0+(?=1)

At that point, just look for the longest sequence for each string.
List<String> seq = new ArrayList<String>(List.of(
        "10010001",
        "100101",
        "1010001",
        "1000001001000101",
        "10010100010000101",
        "101010010000100100001"
));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=1)0+(?=1)");
for (String s : seq) {
    System.out.println(s + " => " + pattern.matcher(s).results()
            .map(m -> m.group().length())
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .orElse(0));
}

Here is also a demo at OneCompiler.

What you're asking for is not something regular expressions can do. Specifically, it is not possible to come up with a value for ??? given:
public int lengthOfLongestZeroSequence(String input) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("???");
  var m = p.matcher(input);
  if (!m.matches()) throw new Fail();
  return m.group(1).length();
}

lengthOfLongestZeroSequence("10010001");
// or, if you prefer, 
lengthOfLongestZeroSequence("145");

And have this program code work. Remember, regular expressions are not named that because they were invented by Mrs. Jane Regular; they are named the concept 'a regular grammar', and what you want doesn't fit within that concept. It's like asking: "I have a fishing pole. I would like to use it as an airplane, how do I do that": You... can't.
Separate from that, this question is weird. Is there an external entity that is forcing you to use regular expressions? I'm just guessing here, but is this what happened:

Somebody (probably a coding exercise) asked you to write a function that returns the length of the longest sequence of zeroes in the base-2 representation of the input.
You went: Huh, that sounds like a job for regular expressions!
You tried some stuff but it didn't quite work; you aren't sure why so you've come to Stack Overflow to ask questions about this.

But if that's what happened, the actual error lies in step 2, and not step 3. Regular expressions are not a good tool for this job. They are incredibly inefficient and regexes aren't good at infinite concepts (and there can be an infinite number of zero-sequences here).
I must use regexes
Given that a single regex cannot do the job any more than you can exceed the speed of light, you write code instead. You can use regexes as part of your job if you must:
public int lengthOfLongestZeroSequence(String input) {
  var p = Pattern.compile("0+");
  var m = p.matcher(input);
  int answer = 0;
  while (m.find()) answer = Math.max(answer, m.group(0).length());
  return answer;
}

assertEquals(3, lengthOfLongestZeroSequence("10010001"));

Actually I just need to count, whatever way is fastest
I assume, then, your input is actually long in = 145, not String in = "10010001".
There are some numeric/binary tricks you can do. Look into the binary operators (&, |, >>, etcetera). For example, check stuff like this blogpost.

It is possible using only regex to find the longest sequence:
(?<=1)(0+)(?=1)(?!.*1\10+1)

See the test case here: https://regex101.com/r/9dMzQW/1
(?<=1)(0+)(?=1)  # any sequence of `0`s in between `1`s, without consuming `1`s, put captured `0`s in group 1
(?!              # negative lookahead, the following text must not match
  .*             # any characters
  1              # `1` literal
  \1             # captured `0`s previously
  0+             # 1 or more `0`s
  1              # `1` literal
)                # end of lookahead

Essentially, it's testing every sequential 0s between two 1s, and see if there're longer sequence after it. If there is, advance to text next sequence, until it couldn't find a longer one. Subsequently finding the longest sequence.
Here's the Java code.
